# Getting Java variables with Javascript, is it cross browser?

Tags: java, javascript, variables, applet, cross-browser

I run my applet like :

```
<applet code="applet.class" codebase="." name="app" width="400" height="250"></applet>
```

and then I this in javascript to get a variable:

```
var string = document.app.getStringX();
```

I've tested it on the browsers I have and it works fine, but does someone knows if this could fail in some browsers?

Comment: I should have been more specific in my answer, and studies have shown that approximately 10% to 20% of browsers do not have Java and/or Javascript enabled.  If you are looking to include anyone, I would offer the functionality of the Applet in another way in your application.  If it is per a client request, then forget this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work in any browser that does not have Javascript and/or Java enabled.